# Rails + jQuery: JS function keeps running automatically on page load

Tags: jquery

I extracted code into a function called `load_shipping_estimates`:

```
    $(function() {
    function load_shipping_estimates() {
        var zip_code = $('#shipping_estimator_text_field').val();
        if (/^\d+$/.test(zip_code) && zip_code.length == 5) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/checkout/estimate_shipping',
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () { $('.ajax_loader').show(); },
                complete: function () { $('.ajax_loader').hide(); },
                data: {"zip_code": zip_code},
                dataType: 'script'
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#estimator_error_message').html('Please enter a 5 digit zip code.');
            return false;
        }
    }

      // it should only happen when I click on #estimate_shipping_link
    $('.ajax_loader').hide();
    $('#estimate_shipping_link').on("click", load_shipping_estimates());


    });
```

It keeps loading once the page loads. As you can see from the last few lines, I only want it to load when the user clicks a link. How do I fix this? I need to extract it to a function because I'm going to reuse it elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function with `load_shipping_estimates()` on start.

```
$('#estimate_shipping_link').on("click", load_shipping_estimates);
```

should do the trick :)

Comment: What's the difference? Just removing the `()`?

Comment: Yes. With code brackets you call a function. But you want to set the function as callback for the click event :) -> without brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

The entire named function is wrapped in `$(function() { });` which makes it self-run on page load

remove the first and last lines and you should be good